# Console.log not displaying any output (NodeJs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, backend, web-deployment

I am trying to console log a piece of JavaScript code through Node.Js but the terminal is not showing any output.

```
const pokemon = require('pokemon');
pokemon.all();
var name = pokemon.random();
console.log(name);
```

Can't even console log a simple line of code

```
console.log("Hello");
```

[Image of terminal after executing node file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFMMt.png)

Comment: post the complete code of file

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that you use node which **is not a nodejs** package but another. If you type `node` on command line, do you see something like this? Especially the message `Welcome to Node.js vxx.xx.x.`

```
hanania@laptop:~$ node
Welcome to Node.js v12.16.3.
Type ".help" for more information.
>
```

Comment: Ok. I figured it out. I was taping into the wrong directory when accessing the .js file from the terminal. Its really dumb.

Answer (score 0):

just try to check out if nodejs is installed successfully on your device by runing

```
node --version
```

and if it doesn't respond with nodejs version you need to reinstall nodejs

Comment: I figured it out. I was accessing the wrong file in a different directory lol. Working with terminal and without a graphical interface is hard and I am dumb.

Comment: no, you are not dumb , we all faced a lot of trivial problems at the beginning so keep going and never stop asking